# Remove String of length 1 from a Collection excluding some values

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of type String with many words, and in some cases they are just single letters. Such as the letter "K".
I am essentially trying to remove all single instance characters, EXCEPT "A" and "I".
Here is the code/regex I was trying, to no avail:

```
//removing all single letters
ArrayList<String> newList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String word : words) {
  newList2.add(word.replace("[BCDEFGHJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ]", ""));
}
words = newList2;
```

Should I not use regex? Is there a better method, or is there a way I am not using regex correctly? From my understanding my implementation, if it even worked, would only replace it with an empty spot, not completely remove the element.. my goal is to remove the element entirely if it exists, perhaps by the .remove method... Not sure how to go about this. (JAVA)

(P.S, ideally I would also remove the "=" and other symbols if they are apparent, but characters is my gripe at the moment)

Comment: Can you show a clear example of input and expected output?

Comment: I am simply using a arraylist called words, and the input is the words I have added in the question. That is the contents of arraylist "words". Using my method, it doesn't do anything and the output is the same. Would you like more information? For example, there is a single "K" in one of the index of words, and I want to write code to remove it entirely perhaps by the .remove function. Except, I do not want to remove A and I characters.

Comment: Do not change a list while iterating over it, that is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: If you are using at least Java 8, consider using the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: Remove from the list, or replace with an empty string?

Comment: Stream.filter() is what you need

Comment: Remove from list completely is my goal. That is my issue, not sure where or how to go about doing this.

Comment: You are not removing anything - rather, every time you find a single-letter string, you add an empty stringg to the end of the list, while leavong the single-letter atring in place.

Answer (score 9):

No need to use stream api for it. `List#removeIf` will suffice here:

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.length() == 1 && ! List.of("A", "I").contains(s))
```

Note: It is a mutative operation.

Comment: `List.of(<args>)` just creates a list of the supplied arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with loop:

```java
for(int i=0; i < newList2.size(); i++){
    if(newList2.get(i).length() == 1){
        if(!newList2.get(i).equals("A") || !newList2.get(i).equals("I")){
            newList2.remove(i)
        }
    }
}
```